# Как извлечь флаги enum в TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

Есть такой enum:

```
const Flags = {
  ONE: 0b01,
  TWO: 0b10
} as const
```

Функция принимает параметр:

```
function some (flags: 0b01 | 0b10 | 0b11) {
  // ...
}
```

Надо использовать автоматическое извлечение типа:

```
// Но такой вариант возвратит только union `1 | 2`
type TFlags = (typeof Flags)[keyof (typeof Flags)]

// Соответственно передать `0b11` в параметр не выходит:
function some (flags: TFlags) {
  // ...
}
some(3)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос: как получить все варианты `1 | 2 | 3`?

Comment: 1) это не Enum. 2) А как TS должен угадать что у вас битовые флаги? И можно ли в функцию передать 0?

Comment: @AlexeyTen 1) это стандартный вариант эмуляции `enum`, который рекомендован в самом последнем абзаце [этой страницы](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#objects-vs-enums). 2) а зачем гадать, там просто должен быть `union` всех возможных значений и `0` добавляется простым `0|Flags`, если он нужен. Нам ведь нужна только автоподсказка и подсветка ошибки. Типов, как таковых, в TypeScript все равно нет, и ничего он угадать не может.

Comment: @AlexanderLonberg, попробуй тут посмотреть [Compute permutations in TypeScript](https://catchts.com/permutations)

Comment: @AlexanderLonberg так там и есть юнион все возможных значений. Всех двух.

Comment: @AlexeyTen Это битовая маска, я ведь не зря написал `0b11`. Т.е. метод может принимать параметр `(Flags.ONE | Flags.TWO)`

Comment: Для TS нет разницы между 0b11 и 3. Он не умеет угадывать что вы хотите битовые маски. Так что придётся как-то явно перечислить (или вычислить) все варианты

Comment: @AlexeyTen Я это написал, чтоб в вопросе было понятно, что это не просто число. _или вычислить(с)_ - так в этом и вопрос - может ли TS обработать числа как конкатенацию строк в ссылке от  Grundy.

Comment: @Grundy Да посмотрел, вот со строкой TS справляется, а числа так складывать, видимо не умеет :(

Comment: @AlexanderLonberg. возможно рано пока

Comment: Ну вот, а говорили Turing complete 

Comment: @AlexeyTen, а разве речь про вывод типов был? :)

Comment: `const some = (flags: TFlags | 3) => { }` ?

Comment: @captain-yossarian Это уже не автоматически. Ниже описал, каким путем пришлось пойти, чтоб хоть как-то не писать все руками.

Answer (score 0):

Решения так и не нашлось.

Пришлось определить все возможные варианты с "говорящими" именами, например:

```
type Bitmask_0__0011 = 0|1|2|3
```

Код что'б не писать вручную, маска ведь может быть и такой `1111_1111`:

```js
// bitmask.js

const param = process.argv.slice(2)
if (!param.length || !/[0-1_]+/.test(param[0])) {
  console.error('Необходимо ввести число в бинарном формате, например 1011 или 11_0011.')
  process.exit()
}

const value = Number(`0b${param[0].replace(/_+/g, '')}`)
const binValue = value.toString(2)
const section = Math.floor(binValue.length / 4) + ((binValue.length % 4) ? 1 : 0)
const bin = binValue.padStart(4 * section, '0').replace(/(?<=).{4}/g, '_$&')
console.log('type Bitmask_0_' + bin + ' = ' +
  [...Array(value + 1).keys()]
    .reduce((a, v) => (((v & value) === v) && a.push(v), a), []).join('|')
)
```

Пример:

```
> node bitmask.js 10_1010
=> Bitmask_0__0010_1010 = 0|2|8|10|32|34|40|42
```

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69089549/typescript-template-literal-type-how-to-infer-numeric-type/69090186?noredirect=1#comment122137982_69090186) you can find how to make a union of numbers in range. Simplified [example](https://tsplay.dev/m0oeqN)